# is there a way to write u-sql queries without using EXTRACT

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory, u-sql

I have a metadata activity output which is a json of blobs in my container. I want to input these names into my foreach activity where some u-sql query is performed on the blob as per the file name. Is it possible?

Comment: can you show a snippet of USQL script that you are using to understand what it needs as input and what part is currently being EXTRACTED that needs to be removed. Its a bit hard to answer your question in the current form

Answer (score 1):

You need to include either a `SELECT` or an `EXTRACT`. Since you are pulling from files, you are going to want to use `EXTRACT`.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to run different U-SQL scripts based on the file name.

There are a couple ways to do this:

1) use If conditions in Data Factory to call different U-SQL scripts based on the file name. Nesting the if statements will allow you to have more than two options. There are [several string manipulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions) functions to help you with this. Say one path is `@item.Contains('a')`.

```
{
    "name": "<Name of the activity>",
    "type": "IfCondition",
    "typeProperties": {
            "expression":  {
                 "value":  "@item() == <file name>", 
                 "type": "Expression"
             }
            "ifTrueActivities": [
            {
                "<U-SQL script = 1>"
            }
        ],

        "ifFalseActivities": [
            {
                "<U-SQL script 2>"
            }
            ]
    }
}
```

2) The second option is to use a single U-SQL script and do the split from there. Again, [string manipulation functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/operators/csharp-functions-and-operators) can help via pattern matching. There is some advantage to this as far as organization goes as you can store the unique scripts in stored procedures and the U-SQL script would simply check the file name passed in and call the relevant stored proc.

```
//This would be added by data factory
DECLARE @fileName = "/Samples/Data/SearchLog.tsv";

IF @fileName == "/Samples/Data/SearchLog.tsv"
THEN
    @searchlog =
        EXTRACT UserId int,
                Start DateTime,
                Region string,
                Query string,
                Duration int?,
                Urls string,
                ClickedUrls string
        FROM "/Samples/Data/SearchLog.tsv"
        USING Extractors.Tsv();

    OUTPUT @searchlog
    TO @fileName
    USING Outputters.Csv();

ELSE
    @searchlog =
        EXTRACT UserId int,
                Start DateTime,
                Region string,
                Query string,
                Duration int?,
                Urls string,
                ClickedUrls string
        FROM @fileName
        USING Extractors.Tsv();

    OUTPUT @searchlog
    TO "/output/SearchLogResult1.csv"
    USING Outputters.Csv();
END;
```

Something to think about is that Data Lake Analytics is going to be more efficient if you can combine multiple files into one statement. You can have multiple `EXTRACT` and `OUTPUT` statements. I would encourage you to explore whether or not you could use pattern matching in your `EXTRACT` statements to split the U-SQL processing without needing the foreach loop in data factory.